# Is it possible to generate docfx documentation from multiple repositories?

Tags: docfx

I have multiple docfx documentation in different repositories.
How can I merge these documentation into one docfx project that contains multiple others?

Using docfx Cross Reference between Projects didn´t solve my problem since it just links me between projects but doesn´t merge.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the best way but I have done this with Azure DevOps build/release pipelines. It did not involve API documentation so I can't speak to whether this would work for that. For what it's worth:

Assuming each repo has its own Markdown files and images...

Create a build pipeline for each repo that publishes its contents as an artifact.

Create a release pipeline...

[image]

...that downloads each artifact to one place.

[image]

DocFx provides a release pipeline task. Add that to the release pipeline.

Create a universal `docfx.json` in a central place. Include paths to each of the downloaded artifacts.

Point the DocFx release pipeline task to the `docfx.json` file.

To apply a custom template, create a repo for the template and follow the same steps: publish it as an artifact, download it with the release pipeline, and reference the directory with the `docfx.json`.

Comment: This is great step-by-step, do you have an example of how to point the docfx.json to the downloaded artifacts? It mine isn't able to find them.

Comment: what if i have one ui page where i ask for repo url and out of that i need to generate doc? which approch is best i tried exe but it tool local path only and i tried nuget which is related with one single project